# How turn off autofill of input text?

Tags: html, laravel

This is my code in laravel 5.8:
 i load 1 table and allow input:

```
 <td><input autocomplete="off" class="inputdata" name="userid" type="text" value="{{$row->userid}}" disabled="true"/></td>
     <td><input autocomplete="off" class="inputdata" name="email" type="text" value="{{$row->email}}"/></td>
     <td><input autocomplete="off"  class="inputdata"name="name" type="text" value="{{$row->name}}"/></td>
    <td><input autocomplete="off" class="inputdata" name="phonenumber" type="text" value="{{$row->phonenumber}}"/></td>
   <td><input autocomplete="off" class="inputdata" name="company" type="text" value="{{$row->company}}"/></td>
```

[image]
At Red Frame, it auto fill a value ( it is username)

I had add : `autocomplete="off"`, but this can't resolve.

How turn off autofill of input text?
I using Google Chrome.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill
chrome (for some reason i don't know) sometimes ignores `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: i try autocomplete="false", autocomplete="new-password", it still not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this advices:

```
 1. Add autocomplete="off" onto <form> (or try do it on <table>) 
    element;

 2. Add hidden <input> with autocomplete="false" as a first children
        element of the form.
```

Comment: Thank you, I had table into a form , add autocomplete="off" onto <form>, it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

**you have use jquery to off the autofill input text...**
**try this code using jquery and add all js and css i think you can get your answer very easily.. **

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
});
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on( 'focus', ':input', function(){
        $( this ).attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    });
});
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').live('focus',function(){
        $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, but my problem  autocomplete='off' is not working.

Comment: i try autocomplete="false", it not ok.

Comment: try this and send me your error screen shot. and you add jquery? you can get easily to use jquery try this one..

Comment: result the same with my image, it still auto fill to red frame.

Comment: can you share screen shot plz

Comment: image in my question

Comment: i try autocomplete="false", it not ok.

Answer (score 0):

//Just use this two line for text field and number field in your from footer.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete','off');
$('input[type=number]').attr('autocomplete','off');

});
```